# I am an administrator but I cannot access a whole drive

Tags: windows-10, permissions

[image]

Basically I want to prevent non administrator to access the whole drives.

So I right click and delete everyone and authenticated users from list of permissions

[image]

So only system and administrators can access that. The rest cannot. The thing is I am administrator.

So why can't I?

I also set my self as owner.

Some comment says that I am showing permission for system account.

I upload another screenshot. The administrators have same permission except special permission. I don't know what special permission means

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is showing the permission for System account not Administrators

Comment: The administrator permissions are the same. I uploaded another screen shot

Comment: Processes don’t have Administrator permissions unless they run Elevated. Remember UAC. So most of the time, you aren’t an Administrator. If you really need groups, create one yourself.

Comment: I am just trying to look at the content of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

how about if u can login with the local administrator and try to access it, by the way Special Permission is the permission given if u want a user to have read, write but not delete

if the above didn't work, try press the **advanced** tab in the  bottom of the Security Window, check the owner and choose ur username in **Select a user** marked by red and check what is the effective access (the actual and applied permission you have on the folder)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean as local administrator? Is that a special account? How do I log in as the local administrator? I

Comment: it means the built in administrator account, right click on **this Computer** then **Manage** then press **Local Users and Groups** then **Users** and check the built in account which is usually called administrator and it is disabled, enable it and put a password for it them log off, in the login screen in the username field put **.\administrator** and the password. now u logged in as administrator

Comment: I can access the folder now if I add authenticated user in permission. The thing is I do not want user to be able to access it simply because it is authenticated. I want only administrator to be able to access it.

Comment: you have to add the users u want to access the folder to the **Administrators** built in group, right click on this **Computer** then **Manage** then press **Local Users and Groups** then **Groups** you will find **Administrators** group, add the users u want to have access to the folder in it